# Getting generic error when installing Selenium C# WebDriver in .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, .net-standard

I've searched for solutions on this but found no one getting this error and it is never very descriptive. Wanted to see if someone has a solution or point me to a resource that covers it.

Basically, I have a .Net Standard 2.0 Project that I'm installing Selenium WebDriver and ChromeDriver to. However, when I try to install them from Nuget Manager in VS2017 (either via Nuget.org or locally), I get the error below:

"The local source 'C:\Users\ME\Desktop\dist' doesn't exist."

I've tried placing ChromeDriver on the desktop thinking that was the cause but no change. Also tried command line install of the Nuget package but it fails as well.

Any assistance would be very helpful.

Comment: When you bring up the NuGet manager, make sure that your package source is set to nuget.org. It sounds like you've got it pointed to some local path that doesn't exist.

Comment: @JeffC That was the issue. I completely forgot that you can specify local sources in NuGet Manager. There was an old local source I had referenced that was causing it. Once removed it appears to have resolved it.

Comment: Added that as an answer, if you want to accept it so the question doesn't get left marked as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bring up the NuGet manager, make sure that your package source is set to nuget.org. It sounds like you've got it pointed to some local path that doesn't exist.